# CLLocationCoordinate2D currentCentre not returning lat/long

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

CLLocationCoordinate2D currentCentre; not returning lat/long when i use my method in ViewDidLoad if i use it viewDidAppear it works but lat/long is coming from somewhere else(not accurate). what i would like to is on viewDidLoad or viewDidApear execute [self queryGooglePlaces:@"grocery"]; this i'm new to this be nice please

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

//Back Button
UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
[[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:back];



self.mapView.delegate = self;     



locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];


[locationManager setDelegate:self];


[locationManager setDistanceFilter:kCLDistanceFilterNone];
[locationManager setDesiredAccuracy:kCLLocationAccuracyBest];


[self.mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];



firstLaunch=YES;
imageName=[[NSString alloc] init];
imageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"park.png"];
[self queryGooglePlaces:@"grocery"];

}


-(void) queryGooglePlaces: (NSString *) googleType
{

// Build the url string we are going to sent to Google. NOTE: The kGOOGLE_API_KEY is a constant which should contain your own API key that you can obtain from Google. See this link for more info:
// https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/#Authentication

NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=%f,%f&radius=%@&keyword=%@&sensor=true&key=%@", currentCentre.latitude, currentCentre.longitude, [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", currenDist], googleType, kGOOGLE_API_KEY];


NSLog(@"test: %@",url);

//Formulate the string as URL object.
NSURL *googleRequestURL=[NSURL URLWithString:url];
//NSLog(url);
// Retrieve the results of the URL.
dispatch_async(kBgQueue, ^{
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: googleRequestURL];
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(fetchedData:) withObject:data waitUntilDone:YES];
});
```

}

my .h code

```
@interface MapViewController : UIViewController<MKMapViewDelegate,CLLocationManagerDelegate>
 {

CLLocationManager *locationManager;


NSString *imageName;
BOOL firstLaunch;

CLLocationCoordinate2D currentCentre;
int currenDist;


}
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;
 -(void) queryGooglePlaces: (NSString *) googleType;
@end
```

but if i call it in button it works like so

```
- (IBAction)toolbarButtonPresses:(id)sender {


imageName=[[NSString alloc] init];
imageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"park.png"];

[self queryGooglePlaces:@"grocery"]; 

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `[locationManager startUpdatingLocation];` in `viewDidLoad` and then check that it has returned a valid location by querying the location property - checking that it isn't nil. It might be taking a while to return a result, so that when the rest of your code executes there isn't a valid value. You might be able to use the `– locationManager:didUpdateToLocation:fromLocation:
– locationManager:didFailWithError:` method in the CLLocationManagerDelegate protocol to handle this.

Comment: hi, i tried to do it this way but it keeps querying never stops here is my code

Comment: -(void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation{
    
    imageName=[[NSString alloc] init];
    imageName=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"park.png"];
    [self queryGooglePlaces:@"grocery"];   
    
    
    
}

Answer (score 0):

Please check your running code in device not in simulator
simulator couldn't given right lat/log position

Comment: i checked it in my device too same thing